# My puppy vomited her food

Tags: health, diet, dogs

We increased the amount of food we gave our puppy, and she was doing okay, but now we have noticed it has been harder for her to make a bowel movement, and she just vomited three times 5 minutes after she ate two tablespoons of food.  The vomit was whole chunks of food, so I am not sure she was even chewing her food up.

Does anyone know the reason why this would happen?

Comment: Any particular reason why you increased her food?

Comment: How long has this been going on for?

Comment: I increased her food from 1/4 cup to 1/2 cup.  She is 14 weeks old, and the bowel movements have been irregular for 2-3 days, and the vomiting started today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of reasons why a dog may vomit is *huge* and many are related to various diseases and illnesses. However, the most common reason is something they ate, as a result of physical composition or drug/poison based. Dogs are often indiscriminate in what they'll eat, and swallow, and the result of this can be vomiting or more serious problems.

I think, at this point, I would strongly recommend that you bring her to the vet for an examination. The fact that she's both vomiting and struggling to defecate signals, to me at least, a serious problem which could be an injury or worse. There's really no way to tell without the examination.

It could be something she ate or she may have developed a food intolerance (very real possibility), and so easy to resolve, but that's still going to need veterinary confirmation.

Comment: I am taking her to the vet in an hour.  It seems as if she isn't chewing her food at all, the food intolerance is a definite possibility.

Comment: I will post the results from the vet visit for all to see.  I wasn't sure if anyone knew why this may be happening or not.

Comment: @JohnJanssen - Good to hear. :)

Comment: Way too many variables really.

Comment: I took her to the animal hospital and she had roundworms, and she also has an upper respiratory infection.  The vet gave her de-wormer and gave me an antibiotic for the infection.  Since she is inhaling the food without chewing, I think I may add a little warm water to her food(There is a recipe on [Food Website](http://bluebuffalo.com) that explains this.  The food may be too hard for her to chew, which is why she feels she has to eat without chewing.

Comment: Another update.  I started spreading the food on the ground to get her to eat, and that helped for a while, then we started to put her food back in the bowl with warm water.  She hasn't had many issues since we've begun  to do this.